# Persisting PowerPoint, PDF, and such document files to Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, file, persistence, document

I've been searching for a way to persist various file types, namely: [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF), [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), [PowerPoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PowerPoint), to a [Postgresql](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database from a web form using [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity). I have come across the binary data type in Postgres, but I'm told that is not best practice.

Is there another way to go about it or is serialization the only option?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “serialization” in this context?

Answer (score 0):

## Storing within the database

If you insist on storing such documents *inside* the database, then yes indeed, [the binary types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html) exist just for that purpose. When you have data that cannot be semantically understood by the database through one of the [many other data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html), then a binary type is the fallback.

Whereas Postgres knows what an integer is, and what a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is, and what a [geo-spatial coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostGIS) is, and knows how to search and sort such values, Postgres has *no* idea how to make any sense or meaning of a PowerPoint or PDF file. Such files are just a bunch of indecipherable bits from the viewpoint of the database engine.

Such file-in-a-field values are known by the cute acronym: [*BLOB*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object), for Binary Large OBject.

## Storing outside the database

Generally the best practice that I have seen is to store such documents *outside* the database, in the persistent storage file system.

In the database, store a string representing the file system path or URL to locate that file when needed.

Comment: I meant the data into the to the database, but I guess whether I persist data in in the database or a file I have to use serialization so I can see hoe the question was confusing. I was really hoping to somehow store the files as objects, but I suppose I'll go with the file system idea. Thanks